# STM32WL55JC1 sampling rate is different

Tags: stm32, c, frequency, clock

I am using STM32Wl55JC1. STM32WL55JC microcontroller multiprotocol LPWAN dual-core 32-bit (Arm® Cortex®-M4/M0+ at 48 MHz). I am trying to do tone calculator. I am using DSP, ADC, DMA and timer for sampling rate.

I am using tone generator and for example if tone is 500 Hz and my fftoutbuffer[16] is going high value (normally 130 but when tone generate is on 174). For 1700 Hz fftoutbuffer[52] is going high value (normally 130 but when tone generate is on 175). I try to calculate my sample rate with this formula.

f_sample = 500 * (1024 / x / 2) = 16 so x= 64000.

f_sample = 1700* (1024 / x / 2) = 52 so x ≈= 64000.

So with these adjustment how can it be 64.000 kHz? I though with these adjustment, I can get 48000000/1000 = 48.000 kHz.

```
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{
TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
htim2.Instance = TIM2;
htim2.Init.Prescaler = 1;
htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
htim2.Init.Period = 1000-1;
htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
{
 Error_Handler();
}
sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_ENABLE;
if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
{
 Error_Handler();
}
}
static void MX_ADC_Init(void)
{
ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
hadc.Instance = ADC;
hadc.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
hadc.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
hadc.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
hadc.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = DISABLE;
hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
hadc.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
hadc.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIG_T2_TRGO;
hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
hadc.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
hadc.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;
hadc.Init.SamplingTimeCommon1 = ADC_SAMPLETIME_79CYCLES_5;
hadc.Init.SamplingTimeCommon2 = ADC_SAMPLETIME_79CYCLES_5;
hadc.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
hadc.Init.TriggerFrequencyMode = ADC_TRIGGER_FREQ_HIGH;
if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
{
 Error_Handler();
}
/** Configure Regular Channel
*/
sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_COMMON_1;
if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
{
 Error_Handler();
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]